# Check If Database Exists in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on project with multiple databases. There is a chance the database may not exists. I am checking to see if the database exists before I run query against the table. The issue is that I am still getting database "Courses" does not exit. I'd like to get rid of that message because I don't want the client to see this message.

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
SET @dbname = N'Courses'

IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname 
OR name = @dbname))
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Courses.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME IN ('isAvailableOnline') AND C.TABLE_NAME IN ('Course'))
    BEGIN
       ALTER TABLE Courses.dbo.Course ADD isAvailableOnline BIT NULL
    END
  END
```

Comment: Aside: Rather than `'[' + name + ']'` you ought to be using [`QuoteName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to quote an object name.

Comment: @HABO, thanks, I will definitely change it to use QuoteName instead.

Comment: You don't need to bother with that anyway as the name in `dbo.sysdatabases` will be stored unquoted. And `dbo.sysdatabases` is deprecated (replaced by `sys.databases` where it will also be unqouted)

Comment: @MartinSmith - In this case it appears that the OP is using `@dbname` as a parameter that _may_ have been quoted, hence the attempt to match it with the value from the table with or without quoting. Yes, they should be using `sys.databases`.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. DB_ID doesn't care if it is quoted or not anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the expression using the potentially non existent database in `EXEC` so it is only compiled if that branch is taken.

I used some shorter idioms for checking database and column existence. If you stick with your existing one for columns it will need to go inside the string that is `EXEC`ed with the quotes doubled up to escape them.

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname
SET @dbname = N'Courses'

IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    IF COL_LENGTH('Courses.dbo.Course','isAvailableOnline') IS NULL
    BEGIN
       EXEC('ALTER TABLE Courses.dbo.Course ADD isAvailableOnline BIT NULL')
    END
  END
```